# defining called class properties via parent class

Tags: php, oop, late-static-binding

I have written a parent class (using late static binding) from which my database classes are inherited. I'm trying to write a constructor to assign each table column as a public property of the child classes. So far i could write the constructor in child classes, which works just fine, but I want to put it in the parent class so that all child classes properties are defined automatically.
Here is my child class:

```
class Sale extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name="invoices";
    protected static $db_fields = array();

    function __construct() {
        global $database;
        $query_cols = " SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '" . self::$table_name . "' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '" . DB_NAME . "' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC";
        $cols = $database->query($query_cols);
        while($col = $database->fetch_array($cols)) {
            if(!property_exists($this,$col['COLUMN_NAME'])) {
                $this->$col['COLUMN_NAME']=NULL;
                array_push(self::$db_fields,$col['COLUMN_NAME']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use this constructor in the parent I need to be able to define the called class property.

```
function __construct() {
    $class_name = get_called_class();
    $query_cols = " SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '" . static::$table_name . "' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '" . DB_NAME . "'";
    $query_cols .= " ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC";
    $cols = $database->query($query_cols);
    while($col = $database->fetch_array($cols)) {
        if(!property_exists($class_name,$col['COLUMN_NAME'])) {
            // the code to define called class public property?!
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you're accessing static members of a class, you can use static::$foo rather than self::$foo, however you would need to redeclare the empty initial static variable for each child class, otherwise it will use the parent's static member.

An alternative approach I use for a Model system, is to use the class name as part of an array structure.

So instead of

```
array_push(self::$db_fields,$col['COLUMN_NAME']);
```

you would do

```
array_push(self::$db_fields[$class_name],$col['COLUMN_NAME']);
```

This way you basically have a single array at the parent class level, with each element an array of the child class fields, keyed by their class name.

Comment: what about public members of class?! for static members we use 'static' but what about public members? how can i apply it?

Comment: static and public aren't mutually exclusive, members can be public, protected or private, and either static or non-static. For a non-static member you'd always be using `$this` (or another variable reference) to access it, so there is no need for `self`, `static`, etc.